# Using Java-8 AES/GCM to authenticate / encrypt parts of a data block

Tags: java, java-8, cryptography, aes-gcm

My task is to use a special feature of AES/GCM to authenticate part A and encrypt part B of a single data block. I have problems with implementing the solution using Java-8.

The following example uses a data block of 256 bit. The first 128 bit shall be authenticated only. The following 128 bit shall be encrypted. The resulting tag for the combined operation is expected to be 128 bit.

I believe I was able to implement an encryption-only variant which encrypts both 128 bit data blocks.

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] initVector   = new BigInteger(96, random).toByteArray();
byte[] data         = new BigInteger(255, random).toByteArray();
byte[] key          = new BigInteger(255, random).toByteArray();
byte[] encrypted    = new byte[data.length];

final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), new GCMParameterSpec(16 * Byte.SIZE, initVector));
cipher.update(data, 0, data.length, encrypted, 0);
byte[] tag = cipher.doFinal();
```

Could anybody give instructions on how to modify the code so that the first 128 bit of data are only authenticated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use one of the [`updateAAD` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#updateAAD-byte:A-).

In your case, something like this (note you need to make the `updateAAD` calls *before* the `update` or `doFinal` calls):

```
cipher.updateAAD(data, 0, 128);              // first 128 bits are authenticated
cipher.update(data, 128, 128, encrypted, 0); // next 128 are encrypted
```

Answer (score 1):

Matt is right that you need to use `updateAAD`. But there are many other things wrong.

For instance, you cannot just use `BigInteger` to create random values. The problem is that for some values there will be an additional `00` value to the left (to encode an unsigned integer) and sometimes it is not. And it may generate too few bytes as well if the number is small.

Furthermore, in Java the tag is considered part of the ciphertext. That's a mistake in my opinion, and it really hurts functionality. But currently that's how it is.

A better way to program this would be something like this:

```
// --- create cipher
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

// --- generate new AES key
KeyGenerator aesKeyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
aesKeyGen.init(256);
SecretKey aesKey = aesKeyGen.generateKey();

// --- generate IV and GCM parameters
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] initVector   = new byte[96 / Byte.SIZE];
random.nextBytes(initVector);
GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, initVector);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey,
        gcmParameterSpec);

// --- process any AAD (just a bunch of zero bytes in this example)
byte[] aad = new byte[128];
cipher.updateAAD(aad);

// --- process any data (just a bunch of zero bytes in this example)
byte[] data         = new byte[128];
// use cipher itself to create the right buffer size
byte[] encrypted    = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(data.length)];
int updateSize = cipher.update(data, 0, data.length, encrypted, 0);
cipher.doFinal(encrypted, updateSize);
```

It generates all the parameters differently and it determines the size of the output buffer dynamically through the `Cipher` instance.

Comment: I already wondered about some weird random effects of my random byte initialization concerning the number of generated bytes. Silly me. Should not have ignored that.

Comment: @Twonky `BigInteger` and quite a few other functions such as integer hex encoding are often wrongly used. Simple tip: if you need binary and you can stay binary, then don't convert to numbers or strings. That actually goes for most types, don't convert unless necessary.

Comment: Are tag length passed to GCMParameterSpec(128) and the size of aad byte array(128) has to be the same value? Are they co-related?